# Jquery Mobile - Ajax call to fetch data from MySql database returning error

Tags: php, json, ajax, jquery-mobile

Jquery Mobile - Ajax call to fetch data from Json data from MySql database returning error.

Here's my code

Server code

```
<?php

try{

header('Content-type: application/json');

$server = "myurl";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$database = "mydb";
$con = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $database) or die       ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
/*mysql_select_db($database, $con);

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Query error: " . mysql_error());
$records = array();
*/
$sql = "SELECT id, l_name AS name, l_lat AS value1, l_long AS value2 FROM     landmarks ORDER BY l_name";
$result= mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$records = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$records[] = $row;
}
mysqli_close($con);
echo json_encode($records); 



} 
catch(Throwable $e) {
$trace = $e->getTrace();
echo $e->getMessage().' in '.$e->getFile().' on line '.$e->getLine().' called from '.$trace[0]['file'].' on line '.$trace[0]['line'];
}





?>
```

my ajax call

```
try {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'myurl',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
        timeout: 5000,
        success: function(data, status){
            $.each(data, function(i,item){ 
                var res = '<h1>'+item.name+'</h1>'
                + '<p>'+item.value1+'<br>'
                + item.value2+'</p>';

                output.append(res);
            });
        },
        error: function(){
           output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
        }
    });

}
catch (e) {

   logMyErrors(e); 
}
```

Here ajax is returning the error function.

But while running the server code in the browser, json data is displayed correctly. 
[image]

Nothing is being logged in the console. Please help to find out what has gone wrong.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: ajax error function is executed

Comment: It looks like you're using the `jsonp` format in the Ajax call, but not returning a JSONP function (just JSON). Try changing to `dataType: json`.

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you.